# change label values in prometheus spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring boot and using default metrices pushed by actuator which is 'http_client_request'. How do I change the value of label named 'uri' of this metric as these Urls are of type '/foo/bar/{id}/response' , hence for each request the Url changes and the count of every request is showing 1 but i want the total count of these Urls irrespective of the {id} value.
Or please suggest how do I handle them.

Can I change the value of uri before pushing default 'http_client_request' metric?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following query:

```
sum by(uri) (
 label_replace(
  label_replace(
   http_client_request{},
   "uri_original", "$1", "uri", "(/foo/bar/[^/]+/response)"
  "uri", "/foo/bar/{id}/response", "uri", "/foo/bar/[^/]+/response"
)
```

Here:

- `sum by(uri)` aggregates data based on same values of label `uri`,
- inner `label_replace` creates copy of `uri` label, to keep label set uniques after application of outer `label_replace`,
- outer `label_replace` replaces label `uri`, when it matches regex `/foo/bar/[^/]+/response` with value `/foo/bar/{id}/response`.

Notice, that `uri` of time series, where it doesn't matches provided regex are not changed.

Comment: Where do I run this query?

Comment: Where you want result. In Grafana for example. Or in Prometheus' web ui, for starters.

Comment: Getting error: 'Error executing query: vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset'

Comment: Can I change the value of uri before pushing default 'http_client_request' metric?

Comment: @Kishan, forgot about lowering uniqueness of labelset. Corrected answer.

Comment: "Can I change the value of uri before pushing default 'http_client_request' metric?" I don't think this is possible from code. Theoretically it could(?) be possible if kubernetes is involved into scraping. But since you basically need an aggregation after retaging, your best shot to make this permanent is to use two recording rules: for aggregated once, and for other.