# How to get prometheus metrics for urls with path params in golang

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics

I have a Golang app that has a URL like this:

```
/app/{userid}/details
```

It takes userid dynamically in URL.

The prom-client based metrics API for HTTP calls is returning all the URLs as separate URLs instead of clubbing them as a single URL with userid as a variable.

```
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/app/123/details"}
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/app/1234/details"}
```

I want the count based on a single URL. e.g.

```
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.003",status_code="200",method="GET",path="/app/{userid}/details"}
```

Comment: Related: how to do this in query described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76621729/21363224)

Comment: Is there a library involved to support that routing pattern in the go program? You could change the label for the Prometheus counter, to use the matched pattern instead of the raw URL path.

Comment: I am using gorilla mux. I couldn't find anything in documentation which returns `/app/{userid}/details`. And can you elaborate more on matched pattern.

Comment: https://www.robustperception.io/prometheus-middleware-for-gorilla-mux - I haven't used gorilla, but check out that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path template from gorilla mux routes.

```
route := mux.CurrentRoute(r)
path, _ := route.GetPathTemplate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be solved at the application level, but you can also solve it in the prometheus configs. To achieve that you can relabel your metric or you may also want to drop the label which causes duplications after this `path` label is dropped you will achieve what you want to do hopefully. To drop the label you can set this config in your `prometheus.yml`.

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - action: labeldrop
    regex: path
```

Reference: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config